# How to prove that every point has an infinite number of neighborhoods?

Tags: real-analysis

My attempt: Suppose that a point $p$ has finite number of neighborhoods. This implies that the set which contains $p$ is non-empty and is finite. But a non-empty finite set cannot be a nbd of any of its points. Thus, there are infinite number of neighborhoods.

Is this correct? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Every point where exactly?

Comment: This depends on the topology

Comment: It is asked just the same in textbook.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify what topological space we're in to have a concrete answer. But assuming we're talking about the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$, no, the proof doesn't work. For example, suppose there are indeed a finite number of neighbourhoods. This is not the same as saying that each such neighbourhood is finite; for example just take $\mathbb{R}$.

Another way to prove this is simply to construct an infinite set of neighbourhoods: Define $S = \{(p-n, p+n: n)\in \mathbb{N}\}$. Clearly $\forall x \in S$, $x$ is a neighbourhood of $p$. $S$ is also infinite (obviously!). Hence there are an infinite number of neighbourhoods of $p$.

Mind you the caveat here is pointed out in the comments, we need to know what space we're working in, and I just assumed $(\mathbb{R}, \tau_{standard})$. Also not sure if it's relevant to the question in your textbook, but the proof I outlined only shows there are a countably infinite number of neighbourhoods.

Comment: Ok thank you so much!!

Comment: The countability restriction is easily removed: just define $S=\{(p-x,p+x):x\in\Bbb R_{>0}\}$.

Comment: @NatashaJ No problem, hope it helped!

Comment: @TonyK Ah yes, not sure why I used $\mathbb{N}$ in the first place actually...